# How can I see the last time a docker image in a private docker hub repository was updated using python

Tags: python, docker

I'm trying to automate some tasks, and as part of the automation I would like to automatically check the last time an image in my private repository was updated using python. I have read some other examples of python code taking advantage of the docker registry api, but haven't had any success making them work. So simply speaking, what I'm trying to do in python is this:

Use python to check the date of the last update for my image in my private repository.
If updated since last pull:
pull new image

If not:
do nothing

I can take care of the rest of what I'm trying to do, I just need a way to find out the last time the image in my private repository was updated. Thanks in advance, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which provider are you using for your private registry? Docker Hub? There is an API that may help you here: https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/

Comment: @Hugo I'm using docker hub for my private repository, I'm just having problems getting that API to work using Python

Comment: Hum, then it seems like it is a different problem than the one asked in your first question, isn't it? You can perform HTTP request with urllib, using it is quite straightforward. What is your problem?